# Scary story anthology where a kid gets killed by a table in his house while his parents are away?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a scary story anthology book where a kid gets killed by a table and his friend gets killed by a window, while his parents are away. It also had pictures showing the kids getting killed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is borderline off-topic if you can't identify any fantasy elements; can you remember anything like that you can [edit] into the question?  Do you remember the cover at all?  When did you read this?

Comment: Nothing other than that is was an anthology book of scary stories that had some pictures and I read it when I was a kid sometime in the 90's.

Comment: Homicidal furniture seems pretty fantastic to me.

Comment: @John Rennie  On the other hand, there was a deer carcass on our property a few yeas ago, under a big tree, and we thought it had been killed by a falling branch which happend to break (possibly due to wind) and then fall due to gravity.  There is no evidence that the tree branch had any fantastic homicidal intentions.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I don't know, tree branches can be.... *shady*.

Answer (score 4):

It's *The Housewarming* in [The slithering corpse & other sinister stories](https://archive.org/details/slitheringcorpse00welc):

> Lloyd realized that the edge of the coffee table was digging into Duncan's waist. He made a move to help his friend, but two dining chairs scuttled over to block him. Duncan began to scream again, and Lloyd saw his shirt wash red as his stomach scissored between the table edge and the door. Then Duncan's torso fell onto the table, and he stopped screaming abruptly.

Hat tip to user166577 whose description lead me to another story in the anthology, *Really Good Chew*.